# How do I add a deleted file to the index to be committed?

Tags: git

I have recently moved a project from SVN to git, and my colleague only just recently deleted all of the old .svn directories.  I attempted to use `git pull --rebase` in order to have his changes (which were numerous) be added *before* my own changes.  There was a conflict, and I was able to use `git add -A` to remove the vast majority of issues.  However, there remains the following:

```
Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both deleted:       th/protected/modules/rights/views/authItem/.svn/text-base/_childForm.php.svn-base
```

If we've both deleted it, how am I supposed to use `git add/rm` to add the change to the index?

In short, how does one go about adding a deleted file to the index to be committed?

EDIT:

I have tried to use `git rm <filename>` on the file, but it does not work it provides the following message:

```
fatal: pathspec 'th/protected/modules/rights/views/authItem/.svn/text-base/_childForm.php.svn-base' did not match any files
```

EDIT:

Would it be worthwhile to make a dummy file of the same name that I can add to the index?  I don't know what might happen, though, so I am unwilling to do this without a little bit of advice.

Comment: How do you even get a conflict that "both deleted"?? If you both deleted it, how is there a conflict? Can you give steps to reproduce?

Comment: My colleague deleted files, and I committed a change to one of the directory names (the one that errors).  Therefore we both deleted something, but it also caused a merge conflict (or something).  If you are able to replicate the issue, definitely let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing `git rm --cached th/protected/modules/rights/views/authItem/.svn/text-base/_childForm.php.svn-base` to remove the file only from the index, not from the working tree.

Reference: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html

Comment: I knew there was such a command to remove files from the index, but I was unable to find it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have a merge conflict. Try `git mergetool` or

```
git add th/protected/modules/rights/views/authItem/.svn/text-base/_childForm.php.svn-base
```

Comment: I tried the "git add" solution, but it provided the same merge error.